# Openerp create function issuing key_error when concatinating field values

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to concatenating '**name**' from "**roster_time**" class and '**type_name**' from "**roster_type**" class and assign those values in to '**name**' field of "**roster_type**" class. But it's issuing Key error. Please help me to solve this.

***Roster Time class***

```
class roster_time(osv.osv):
    _name = "roster.time"
    _description = "To create roster time slot"

    _columns = {
         'roster_id':fields.integer('Roster ID'),
         'start_time': fields.char('Start Time',required=True),
         'end_time':fields.char('End Time',required=True),
         'rostertype':fields.many2one('roster.type','roster','Roster Time'),
         'name':fields.char('Roster Time',required=True),
    }

    def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        start = vals['start_time']
        end = vals['end_time']
        name = str(vals['start_time']) +'-' + str(vals['end_time'])

        vals.update({'name': name})

        return super(roster_time, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)

roster_time()
```

***Roster Type***

```
class roster_type(osv.osv):
    _name = "roster.type"
    _description = "To create roster type for each department"

    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Roster type'),
        'type_name': fields.char('Type Name'),
        'roster': fields.one2many('roster.time','rostertype','Time Slot',required=True),
        'date_allocation_connection': fields.many2one('roster.days.allocation', 'type_connection', 'Date Allocation Connection'),
        'roster_time_connection': fields.many2one('roster.time','Slot'),
        'department_id': fields.many2one('hr.department','Department'),
    }

    def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        slot_id = self.pool.get('roster.time').browse(cr,uid, vals['roster_time_connection']).id
        slot_name = self.pool.get('roster.time').browse(cr,uid, slot_id).name        
        name = str(vals['type_name']) +'-' + str(slot_name)

        vals.update({'name': name})

        return super(roster_type, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)


roster_type()
```

Comment: Is it the full create method? in the `roster_time` `create` method, unused the `start` and `end` variables, but this may not the problem. Once I had similar magic key error issue, it solved when I restarted openERP and updated the module.

Comment: ah , no I just used those variables in some validation rules and removed that part since the question getting lengthy and it's not relevant on this